# AFNetworking response for non English Characters

Tags: json, unicode, afnetworking

This is my code:

```
 AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request


                                  success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){

                                      NSLog(@"JSON : %@",JSON);


                                  }

                                  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                      NSLog(@"Failed %@",error);

}];
```

The request is successful and I get the JSON back. The problem here is that the returned JSON contains some greek characters which are showing like that:

U03c9\U03c1\U03b1\U03af\U03b1 \U03b5\U03c6\U03b1\U03c1\U03bc\U03bf\U03b3\U03ae!

On my browser the result is ok. How to force xcode to understand every non english characters? (Eg. chinese or russian)

Comment: AFNetworking uses NSJSONSerialization, which does this by default out of the box.  Is your server configured with UTF-8 still?

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking handles all unicode characters, provided that the server is setting the correct character encoding and data.

Nothing appears to be wrong with your code—this has everything to do with what the server is sending back.

Answer (score 0):

\U03c1 is a piece of JSON syntax, it appears because you print JSON as a NSString.  Check this [Objective-C: NSString not being entirely decoded from UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838372/objective-c-nsstring-not-being-entirely-decoded-from-utf-8)